# Functionally rewriting assignment from an Optional without executing "else" logic

Tags: java, option-type, functional-java

I have the following in my code:

```
Optional<Foo> optionalFoo = fooDAO.findByName(name);
Foo foo;
if(!optionalFoo.isPresent()) {
    foo = fooDAO.addFoo(name);
} else {
    foo = optionalFoo.get();
}
```

IntelliJ popped up a hint that said `can be replaced with single expression in functional style`. I tried replacing this block with:

```
Optional<Foo> optionalFoo = fooDAO.findByName(name);
Foo foo = optionalFoo.orElse(fooDAO.addFoo(name));
```

This caused tests to fail, as `fooDAO.addFoo(name)` is called regardless of whether or not the `Optional` is empty, and the logic within `addFoo` should not be run if the `Foo` already exists.

Is it possible to rewrite the original block functionally without calling `fooDAO.addFoo(name)` unless it's necessary?

Comment: @Leviand I believe it's calling `fooDAO.addFoo(name)` in order to get its return value, which is what is passed to `orElse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `orElseGet`, which accepts a `Supplier` that is only invoked when the value is not present:

```
Foo foo = fooDAO.findByName(name)
    .orElseGet(() -> fooDAO.addFoo(name));
```

I think that `name` needs to be effectively final for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Use Optional.orElseGet with a lambda expression:

```
Optional<Foo> optionalFoo = fooDAO.findByName(name);
Foo foo = optionalFoo.orElseGet(()->fooDAO.addFoo(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

`orElse` take a value as an argument, so the function you passed always executed.

To create `foo` if necessary , you should use `orElseGet`:

```
Foo foo = fooDAO.findByName(name).orElseGet(() -> fooDAO.addFoo(name));
```